# How to interface Raspberry pi B with 433 Mhz Transceiver kit (WiringPI is defunct)?

Tags: wireless, radio

I picked up a 433 Mhz transceiver kit so I can mess around with a remote controlled power outlet from my PI. Thing is, the [two](https://kyleflan.wordpress.com/2017/11/03/pirfecto-a-raspberry-pi-wireless-outlet-system/) the [examples](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/martinohmann/rfoutlet@v0.1.0) I find for it use the [WiringPI](http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/) library which appears to be defunct.

Is there another way to code with [this kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01H2D2RH6) from a PI?

edit - specs are:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS    : 697.95
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : 0003
Serial      : 00000000564a300b
Model       : Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 1

# raspinfo 
System Information
------------------

Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 1
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
```

Comment: Post the specifications of the device you are attempting to connect.

Comment: @Milliways - It's an older B series board running Raspbian/RaspiOS

Comment: This is hardly a specification of the device you are attempting to connect. Without knowing this no one can answer and the link to the "kit" is remarkably unimformative

Comment: Your 433MHz kit might be called  ***MX-05***. You can find more references from this chat: Transmitting and Receiving messages through RF433 using Raspberry Pico - Chat 
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/130758/2021/10/22

Comment: @tlfong01 - I see. Yes, you are correct. Thanks for the link. On the back of the receiver is screenprinted "MX-RM-5V 080408". I thought Millways wanted the type of Raspi I was using. I thought the link to amazon would be enough info for the more experienced to offer some insight.

Comment: Another "`wiringpi` is deprecated" rumor. Where do these come from? On my RPi 3B+ bullseye, getting `wiringpi` installed is still done with the normal apt sequence: `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt install wiringpi`. Also know that [WiringPi is now maintained by a team on GitHub](https://github.com/WiringPi) since Gordon threw in the towel.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ran across a fork of WiringPI for anyone interested. I've been looking for days and not sure why it took a post here before actually finding it. I compiled this along with 433Utils and it's fine:
https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/tree/final_official_2.50

Comment: I should mention, although the `RPi_Utils` directory compiles, I am not seeing any codes when running `RFSniffer`. Pretty sure I have the wiring hooked up correctly with the customary RX data pin on GPIO27, and TX data pin on GPIO17. Even using `codesend` produces no output so something is amiss here. Not sure if it's my hardware or the software at this point.